# Changing alert() to getElementByID()

Tags: javascript

How would I replace `window.alert()` with `document.getElementByID().innerhtml` to alert a message output using the more modern above method?

This is what I have so far.

#### My HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Alert Box Replacement</title>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>JavaScript</h1>
    <h2>Javascript basics</h2>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### My JS :

```
var response = confirm('Proceed to Checkout?');
var message;
if (response ==true) {
    message ="Checkout";
} else {
    message ="Continue Shopping";
}
alert(message);
```

Thanks!

Comment: None of your elements have an ID, so there's that. And which element did you want to change the innerHTML of?

Comment: @user5904242 Can you rephrase your question? Are you trying to change an element's text content instead of alerting? If so, why don't you write your own function that changes an element's text instead of trying to overwrite `window.alert`?

Comment: Was trying to use alert but not use window.alert()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing the `innerHTML` of an HTML element based on the outcome of a `confirm` statement, is as simple as this :

```js
if (confirm('Proceed to Checkout?')) {
   document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = "Checkout";
} else {
   document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = "Continue Shopping";
}
```

```html
<h1>JavaScript</h1>
<h2>Javascript basics</h2>
<div id="message"></div>
```

(see also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/snr1v81L/))